# Adding line breaks and bold in an equation

Tags: equations, bold

Trying to have something laid out like this

[image]

I tried this code but it throws up some non-aligned messy solution. Anyone know of any fixes?

```
\begin{equation}
\textbf{1. Forecast:} \\[10pt]
\begin{aligned}
x_{t + 1}^f = M_{t + 1} x_{t }^a \\[10pt]
P_{t + 1}^f = P^b \\[10pt]
\end{aligned}
\textbf{2. Update:} \\[10pt]
\begin{aligned}
K_{t + 1} = P^b H^T (HP^bH^T  + R_{t + 1})^{-1} \\[10pt]
x_{t + 1}^a = x_{t + 1}^f  + K_{t + 1}(y_{t + 1} - H x_{t + 1}^f) \\[10pt]
P_{t + 1}^a = P^b \\[10pt]
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

So thanks to the answer below for providing a solution which can be seen below. I now would like the text to be further aligned to the left as in the picture above. Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: An obvious solution would use a single `aligned` environment, and `\intertext{\textbf{2. Update:}}` (no \\ afterwards).

Comment: Thank you. I will try this and report back!

Comment: Feel free to ask if you have any problem!

Comment: See my updated question. It worked but I have a follow up to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

(red lines show text borders)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\intertext{\textbf{1. Forecast:}}
x_{t + 1}^f     & = M_{t + 1} x_{t }^a    \\
x_{t + 1}^f     & = M_{t + 1} x_{t }^a    \\
P_{t + 1}^f     & = P^b                   \\
\intertext{\textbf{2. Update:}}
K_{t + 1}       & = P^b H^T (HP^bH^T  + R_{t + 1})^{-1} \\
x_{t + 1}^a     & = x_{t + 1}^f  + K_{t + 1}(y_{t + 1} - H x_{t + 1}^f) \\
P_{t + 1}^a     & = P^b 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

**Addedndum:**
Since text between equation systems is short, you might consider reduce space around `\intertext` by use `\shortintetext` defined in the `mathtools` package  (as suggested Barbara Benton in her comment):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-2]
\begin{align*}
\shortintertext{\textbf{1. Forecast:}}x_{t + 1}^f     & = M_{t + 1} x_{t }^a    \\
P_{t + 1}^f     & = P^b                   \\
\shortintertext{\textbf{2. Update:}}
K_{t + 1}       & = P^b H^T (HP^bH^T  + R_{t + 1})^{-1} \\
x_{t + 1}^a     & = x_{t + 1}^f  + K_{t + 1}(y_{t + 1} - H x_{t + 1}^f) \\
P_{t + 1}^a     & = P^b
\end{align*}
\lipsum[1][3-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Given the length of the text. `\shortintertext` might look better.  (Requires `mathtools`.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton, you are right. I didn't use it because OP insert between each equation line 10pt ... I will ad new example as you suggest. Thank you very much!

Comment: With regular `\intertext` on number 1 and `\shortintertext` on number 2, the gap between item and first display line is not the same (larger on number 1).  I was thinking of `\shortintertext` on both, but have never used it at the beginning, so don't know about side effects above it.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, you are right again. I overlooked the first inter text :-(. Corrected now.